# blur is working only for one textbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net

```
$("span").hide();    

$("#<%=textbox1.ClientID%>").blur(function(){

    if($("#<%=textbox1.ClientID%>").value == ""){
        $("#<%= label1.ClientID%>").text = "This cannot be left blank"
         $("#<%= label1.ClientID%>").show();
    }
    else{
        $("#<%= label1.ClientID%>").hide(); 
    }
});

$("#<%=textbox2.ClientID%>").blur(function(){

    if($("#<%=textbox2.ClientID%>").value == ""){
        $("#<%= label2.ClientID%>").text = "This cannot be left blank"
         $("#<%= label2.ClientID%>").show();
    }
    else{
        $("#<%= label2.ClientID%>").hide(); 
    }
});

<table action="demo_form.asp">
     <tr>
         <td>First Name:</td>
         <td><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
         <td><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>Last Name Name:</td>
         <td><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
         <td><asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label></td>
     </tr>
```

I have 4 labels and 4 textboxes. I want to show a message saying "This cannot be left blank" if it is left blank. The above code works for textbox1. It does not work for textbox 2. Also, is there a better way to do this? Where I can minimize my code. I need to do the same thing for 4 textboxes and 4 labels.

Comment: can you share output html at fiddle

Comment: I would need to see your HTML structure. But basically you'll give a class to each of these inputs and then bind this to the class (so all of them) and then make use of `$(this)`.

Comment: You have two labes with `ID="Label1"` and no label with `ID="Label2"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are lots of validation plugins. you tried to do with blur for empty inputs so here is solution

hope it helps

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K6SPU/2/)

```
$(".blur").blur(function () {

  var label = $("#label-" + $(this).prop("id"))

  if ($(this).val() == "") {
    label.show().text("This cannot be left blank");
  } else {
    label.hide();
  }

});
```